# How would I integrate .live() into this function?

Tags: javascript, live, jquery

I want to integrate .live() into this function:

```
$('a.oembed').each(function(){
    $(this).embedly({maxWidth:400,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
        $(this).parent().append($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 })).children('img').wrap('<div class="thumbnail_border" />');

    });
});
```

so that it will be triggered once new elements are loaded. How would I do this?

Comment: check this out: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-live-with-each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why use use each at first place..

```
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:400,'method':'replace'}).live('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
        $(this).parent().append($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 })).children('img').wrap('<div class="thumbnail_border" />');
    });
```

---

If you want the embedly method to take different values while applying it then you should use the each just for that part

```
$('a.oembed')
    .each(function(){
               $(this).embedly({maxWidth:400,'method':'replace'});
             })
    .live('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
               $(this).parent()
                      .append($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 }))
                      .children('img')
                      .wrap('<div class="thumbnail_border" />');
             });
```

Comment: because I want to make the API call for one element at a time... will .live do this automatically?

Comment: If you want to apply the `embedly` plugin for dynamically added elements then you cannot do that with live. Live is for binding events only. To apply the plugin you would need to call the API whenever you add new elements in the DOM.

Comment: your new code gives this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: embedly is not defined`